# Are QSPI Interface and SPI compatible one with another?

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I have an SPI device (flash memory) and want to connect it to a microcontroller (nRF52840) which supports both SPI and Quad-SPI. Can the SPI device work in Quad-SPI mode in order to use the Easy-DMA provided by the microcontroller or are SPI and Quad-SPI incompatible?

Comment: *Find/read the datasheets please*. This topic cover many pages of details including modes of communication. QSPI simply has 4 data lines so nibbles can be transported instead of a single data line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put in an external flash memory chunks of program and to load them in RAM in order to be executed in nrf51822 and nrf52832 microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393892/how-to-put-in-an-external-flash-memory-chunks-of-program-and-to-load-them-in-ram) this is an implementation detail of your existing **unresolved** question,  it should not be an new post.

Answer (score 3):

It obviously depends on particular "an SPI device".

If you are using the Cypress S25FL064P as external memory (as per your other inquiry), it does support both standard SPI (with MISO-MOSI) and four-lane QSPI (four bi-directional wires), see [specifications](http://www.cypress.com/file/196856/download) (!!!).

The nrf52840 also has two distinctive interfaces, SPIM (SPI Master) and QSPI. Both are using "EasyDMA", whatever it is. Again, read [specifications](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52840_OPS_v0.5.pdf) for God's sake please.